# adhuc + negative clause: inclusive or exclusive of present?

Tags: adverb, time

<sub>[Cdl. Cajetan](https://forum.musicasacra.com/forum/discussion/18914/organs-not-played-in-churches-in-the-13th-century#Item_1)'s early 16<sup>th</sup> cen. [commentary on an article of St. Thomas Aquinas's *Summa Theologica*](https://forum.musicasacra.com/forum/discussion/18914/organs-not-played-in-churches-in-the-13th-century#Item_1):</sub>

> ***adhuc** Romana Ecclesia coram Summo Pontifice **non** utitur [organum].*
>
> <sub>**until now** the Roman Church does **not** use an organ in the presence of the Supreme Pontiff.</sub>

Does this mean an organ is now used in the presence of the pope, when before it was not?

*Lewis & Short* says [*adhuc*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=adhuc#lexicon) means

> *hitherto, thus far* (designating the limit, **inclusive** of the whole space traversed

But is the present included when *adhuc* is followed by a negative clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it means that an organ is still (including today) not used in the presence of the pope.

One would have to change [the tense of *utor*](https://www.verbix.com/webverbix/go.php?&D1=9&T1=utor) from *utitur* (present indicative) to a perfect tense, which shows the action was completed some time in the past: *usus est* (perfect) or *usus erat* (pluperfect).

Perhaps a clearer English translation would be:

> the Roman Church **still** does not use an organ in the presence of the Supreme Pontiff.

---

<sup>what Cdl. Cajetan did not say:</sup>

> <sup>**until now** the Roman Church **did not use** [perfect] an organ in the presence of the Supreme Pontiff.</sup>

<sup>or</sup>

> <sup>**until now** the Roman Church **had not used** [pluperfect] an organ in the presence of the Supreme Pontiff.</sup>